# Load static CSS path in Phoenix layout or template file

Tags: elixir, template-engine, phoenix-framework

I have a layout file which is loaded on several routes. Inside my layout file, I load the CSS:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" media="screen" />
```

This correctly loads my file from https://myurl.com/css/app.css

However, this only works when visiting the base path of my application "/". For example, if the user visits /user, then I end up with https://myurl.com/user/css/app.css

How do I correctly refer to my static CSS path inside my templates and layouts?

Comment: You mean like `href="/css/app.css"`?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Can't believe I didn't see the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To load the CSS file relative to the root of the site, just prepend `/` to the `href`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css" media="screen" />
```